# Is it support .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle 2.0 for .NET Core 1.0 app

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-1.1

Steps taken:

Environment: IIS 7.5 , Visual studio 2015 update 3, Install .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle,configured in machine ,and gave permission for publish folder,and changed to .net managed code.

Question?
its about vs2015 update 3 hosting with iis and not for vs 2017 hosting in iis.
I have created an asp.net  core webapi project in vs 2015 update 3, the api works fine in local machine while publishing i am getting below error.I have installed Windows Server Hosting bundle 2.0 in windows7 machine. is it support for 1.0 or i need to install specific version.

if i need to install specific version means where i will get it and what are the steps needs to do.
In asp.net core webapi project when I am created , the project.json file is like this .

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

when look into the event logger?

Event LOg ERROR:

```
ISMANAGER_CRASH

IIS Manager terminated unexpectedly.

Exception:System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Cannot call disconnect on a proxy.
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.Disconnect(MarshalByRefObject obj, Boolean bResetURI)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.HostingEnvironmentShutdownComplete(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.HostingEnvironmentShutdownComplete(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost)
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.OnAppDomainUnload(Object unusedObject, EventArgs unusedEventArgs)

Process:InetMgr



                                                                          But Dotnetcli version when check with command prompt , [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Error:
[image]
The core api works fine in local machine, only problem after published with iis 
 i am getting below error in iis

Comment: if you are targeting 1.0 then you have to have 1.0 installed...

Comment: You might want to get Vs 2017 Community Edition to take advantage of .nET Core 2.0, present setup won't work.

Comment: I found this post and hope it will solve your problem http://dotnet4europeanhosting.hostforlife.eu/post/European-ASPNET-Core-Hosting-HostForLIFEeu-How-to-Fix-Error-5025-Process-Failure-in-ASPNET-Core.aspx